# Set value to NULL if referenced entry does not exist

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a column in one table referencing a column in another. Nulls are allowed and if an entry in the second table is deleted, the referencing column in the first table is set to null. However, if I try to insert a row in the first table referencing a value that doesn't exist in the second table, the insert fails. How can I force that column to default to NULL if the referenced value doesn't exist while still inserting the row?

Comment: You don't mention the database, but I think in any of them, you will need an explicit trigger to re-set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete reference constraint between two tables. It won't tie two tables into data consistency.
Not sure what you are trying to do, but it is not a good practice for relational database